# How many total BDs and DVDs did The Virgin Witch Maria (Junketsu no Maria) sell?

Tags: anime-production, junketsu-no-maria

Pretty simple question.  How many total BDs and DVDs did The Virgin Witch Maria (Junketsu no Maria) sell?  I wanted to know how well it sold and I don't really know where to find that kind of information, so I decided to ask it here :D

Comment: Please specify a date range or time frame. This site might be what you're looking for http://www.someanithing.com/

Comment: The date range would be since release until now.

Comment: From SomeAniThing. Roughly around 3-3.1K Sales. Sadly, that is extremely poor sales.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From SomeAniThing (A Website that takes into account, BR/DVD Sales from Oricon Charts & Amazon): *"The Virgin Witch Maria"* sold around 3,100 Sales, from all the volumes of BR & DVD.

This is unfortunate sales, for the series. The odds of a sequel is extremely low.

http://www.someanithing.com/3059
You can locate the sales, for exact units. On this link. Just look for "Junketsu No Maria" and total up the sales per volume.